# How to express reduction by a specific amount?

Tags: vocabulary

The word "decimate" literally means to reduce by eliminating 10%.  If there is a general way to express reduction by eliminating a percent or fraction, I can't think of it.  How would you express reduction by eliminating 1/4 or 1/2?

Comment: ***Decimate*** doesn't simply mean reduce by 10%: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/decimate

Comment: The 10% is the historical origin.  You only need to worry about that if you're an ancient Roman soldier.  :-)  Modern usage isn't a specific percentage.  I'm not aware of terms similar to decimate that refer to specific percentages.  "Half" is sometimes used as a verb to mean reduce in half.  Quarter used as a verb means to divide into four pieces, so that's not the same.  You could go with "sale lingo": 10% off, 1/4 off, etc.